# How to use HTML and CSS as a Java application GUI?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, user-interface

I want to design new Git client with a clean GUI.

Is it possible to use the power of HTML, CSS and JavaScript in a java application?

I would like to use Java + JGit for models, Java for controllers and HTML + CSS + JavaScript for views.

I don't want a client-server model. I would like to integrate Java and HTML nicely. A DOM event would fire events directly to a Java controller. This way it would be possible to create rich offline application.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can embed web browser component into your Java Swing/JavaFX Desktop application that displays GUI built with HTML5+CSS+JavaScript. You can see an article that describes how to do this at https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/tutorials/cross-desktop-apps.html

One of the Java Swing/JavaFX libraries that allows embedding Chromium into Java applications is [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser). Using JxBrowser API you can load any web page and work with its DOM and JavaScript. You can even call Java methods from JavaScript code and vice versa. For example:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSFunctionCallback;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSObject;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSValue;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.FinishLoadingEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.LoadAdapter;

public class JavaScriptJavaSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
                if (event.isMainFrame()) {
                    Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
                    JSObject window = (JSObject)
                            browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
                    window.setProperty("MyFunction", new JSFunctionCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public Object invoke(Object... args) {
                            for (Object arg : args) {
                                System.out.println("arg = " + arg);
                            }
                            return "Hello!";
                        }
                    });
                    JSValue returnValue = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(
                            "MyFunction('Hello JxBrowser!', 1, 2, 3, true);");
                    System.out.println("return value = " + returnValue);
                }
            }
        });
        browser.loadURL("about:blank");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use Scala.js to compile scala to javascript.

Comment: You still have to bridge things from JVMWorld to JSWorld

Comment: That's true. To make it possible API provides wrappers for JavaScript primitive types (JSValue) and objects (JSObject).

Comment: To add jxbrowser isn't FOSS and asks $1,799 for a single developer license. This may make it a no go for some people.

Comment: Whew! I've been looking for something that would allow a native Java desktop app with HTML/JS/CSS support, but $1800? I guess I get it, but that sure is a hefty price point. I guess I'm just used to Apache licensed open source products.

Answer (score 7):

It's not really feasible. Rich clients in Java are done using Swing or SWT.

If you want to use HTML/CSS for your user interface, you need to use the server/client model. It can be as simple as creating a local server and launching a browser that connects to it, but it would still be that model.

If you absolutely need to have HTML/CSS as your UI framework and can't go to a server/client model, your best bet is probably looking at something like Google Native Client, but that uses C/C++ bindings on the backend. I haven't used Native Client so I can't personally give much more information on that front.

**Edit to add:**

One option is to embed a native browser into your Swing app using something like: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/

There are some pure Java HTML renderers, however, they most likely won't be fully HTML5/CSS3 compliant, let alone possibly have Javascript bugs as well.

See here for some of those options: [Pure Java HTML viewer/renderer for use in a Scrollable pane](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2438201/84378)

Comment: Yep I think I will have to use a client-server model. The advantage is that people could use their own browser and they could remotely manage their locals git repos.

Answer (score 4):

Like @Reverand Gonzo says, you will need some form of server/client. But you could easily [embed a Jetty server into a Java app and then use GWT for your client code](http://brandontilley.com/2010/03/27/serving-a-gwt-application-with-an-embedded-jetty-server.html).

Comment: How would the user access UI? Via web browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can bring in the power of HTML,CSS,JavaScript into your Swing app using [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) to embed JavaFX WebView. Have a look at the SimpleSwingBrowser demo in this link:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

WebView allows to call JavaScript functions from Java and vice versa. It is also a nice way to enhance your legacy Java app with web technologies.

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX 2.2 brought this functionality  to providing a user interface component (GUI) that has web view and full browsing functionality.

For more details, see  [Adding HTML Content to JavaFX Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular.js with HTML and rest of the things as same in Java, just use classes for business logic, no need to write code for awt/swing. Angular with spring boot are rapid development in Java for webapp with less code in Java without swing use to create best webapp .

Comment: This is a very broad answer. Please try to include some explanation or details about what you're recommending. For example: "just use classes for business logic". That's so broad as to be essentially useless.