# Is it possible create a Java desktop GUI with HTML?

Tags: java, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use HTML and CSS as a Java application GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176981/how-to-use-html-and-css-as-a-java-application-gui)

I'm trying to found another way to create GUIs for Java programs without Swing. I want something more dynamic and easy to use than Swing.

There is anything that I can use for this?

In truth, I want something similar to HTML. Exists?

Comment: What do you mean by "more dynamic"? Easier to change?

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry, my question was incomplete. I'm searching for something similar as HTML, CSS and Javascript usage. Something where I can define areas, add and remove contents, fields in a easy way.

Comment: *"I want something similar to HTML."*  How does HTML offer key-bindings, or adding accelerators for form controls or (..etc.)?  While HTML/CSS and Swing have some commonalities, and in some cases HTML/CSS offers some layout abilities not immediately available in Swing (e.g. the CSS style `float` positioning system), the two are different technologies for different circumstances.  I think that by the time you reduce Swing to what HTML can achieve, it would be a pretty 'poor' substitute for a 'rich' client desktop app.

Comment: If you would have asked for something more dynamic than HTML, I might have suggested Swing. :)

Answer (score 1):

[JavaFX 2.0](http://javafx.com/) might be what you are looking for (ignore JavaFX 1.0 which is very outdated):

- It has an HTML-style layout language called [FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).
- It also allows skinning of user interfaces with CSS-style themes.
- It also has a WebView component that allows you to embed any web / HTML content in your app.

Having said that, I don't think Swing is hard to use when you get used to it, particularly if you use an [improved layout manager like MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: You might also check how to create HTML/CSS/JavaScript based GUI in Java Desktop application: http://java.dzone.com/articles/htmlcssjavascript-gui-java-0