# Web Browser Control in Java?

Tags: java, webbrowser-control

I come from a C# background. We have something called a [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8) control that can load HTML Pages and interact with Javascript using C#.

I would like to interact with an HTML / Javascript page using Java. Are there any well known WebBrowser controls/objects or libraries for Java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176981/how-to-use-html-and-css-as-a-java-application-gui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm
I think this is the widget you're looking for. From the official JavaFX website.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options including commercial and open-source solutions.

**[JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html)**

JavaFX is available in Java 8-10. It [provides](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/overview.htm) the `WebView` control that you can embed into your JavaFX application to display HTML and web pages. It's based on WebKit and renders HTML **off-screen** using Java Graphics API. It's [lightweight](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/mixing-components.html). In Java 11 JavaFX is no longer available. It was extracted into a separate project — [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/).

Runs on Windows, macOS, Linux.

**[JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser)**

It's a commercial library. It [provides](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/browser-view.html#embedding) the `BrowserView` controls for Swing, JavaFX, SWT. It's based on Chromium, so the modern web pages look exactly as in Google Chrome. It supports two [rendering modes](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/browser-view.html#hardware-accelerated): **off-screen** (lightweight) and **hardware accelerated** (GPU-accelerated, heavyweight).

Runs on Windows, macOS, Linux, Linux 64-bit ARM.

**[JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/src/master/)**

It's an open-source library that represents Java port for [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/) (C/C++). As far as I know it supports only Swing. It's based on Chromium, so the modern web pages look exactly as in Google Chrome.

Runs on Windows, macOS, Linux.

---

**What's the difference?**

In 2018 Sebastian Barth compared different Java libraries including JavaFX, JCEF, JxBrowser etc. and shared the results in the [Browser Integration in Java Applications](https://blog.disy.net/swing-browser-integration/) article.

Answer (score 1):

One more option - https://github.com/shannah/webviewjar - very thin library, leverages the OS-built in browser, so the entire library is less than 1mb - and that's with macOS, Windows, and Linux native shims all in one jar.