# What's the best way to display html via java

Tags: java, webview

what is the best way to view html (from url or file) using java? i had try using flyingsaucer. fail. then i move to JEditorPane. fail. then i try lobo. fail. would anybody suggest me anything else

Comment: What problem did you have with `JEditorPane`?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just display html file in java swing, consider the [java swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) from oracle. Check out the [code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextSamplerDemoProject/src/components/TextSamplerDemo.java) on how to read the file through the method `createEditorPane()`. I have also found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438201/pure-java-html-viewer-renderer) for other libraries which you might want to try out.