# simple web browser which can parse css page too

Tags: java, swing, browser, jeditorpane

I am designing a web browser..It Is displaying the web pages but now the problem is....it is not parsing the  page properly (i.e when i browse for "Google" page with my web browser,it is displaying but with a blue background and not aligned properly too)....can anyone help me by saying how to parse(cascading style sheet) in HTML with java swing,,A part of code is displayed below

```
class Page extends JPanel implements Action Listener
{
JPanel head;
 JTextField addrbar;
JEditorPane webpage;
JScrollPane scr;
JLabel statusbar;
JButton homebtn,refreshbtn,gobtn,hisbtn,bookbtn,shbtn;    
public Page()
{        
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    head=new JPanel(); 
    head.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    homebtn=new JButton("Home");
homebtn.addActionListener(this);
head.add(homebtn);

addrbar=new JTextField(100);
addrbar.addActionListener(this);
    head.add(addrbar);   

    gobtn=new JButton("Go");
    gobtn.addActionListener(this);
    head.add(gobtn);

hisbtn=new JButton("History");
System.out.println("action");
hisbtn.addActionListener(this);
head.add(hisbtn);

bookbtn=new JButton(new ImageIcon("Z://Browser/Source/Resources/Images/bkk.jpg"));
    bookbtn.addActionListener(this);
    head.add(bookbtn);

shbtn=new JButton("Show Bookmarks");
shbtn.addActionListener(this);
head.add(shbtn);

     refreshbtn=new JButton("Refresh");
     head.add(refreshbtn);

     statusbar=new JLabel();   

    try{                      
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    PrintWriter ps=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Z://Browser/Source/history.txt",true));
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = new Date();



  //  ps.print(url +"_"+date.getDate()+"_"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"#");
    ps.print(url +"_"+dateFormat.format(date1)+"#");
    ps.close();             
    addrbar.setText(url.toString());
        webpage=new JEditorPane(url);
        webpage.setEditable(false);
    webpage.addHyperlinkListener(new SimpleLinkListener(webpage,addrbar,statusbar));
        scr=new JScrollPane(webpage, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        add(head,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scr,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(statusbar,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        System.out.println(getSize());
      }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
}
```

Comment: `JEditorPane` only has limited CSS support and HTML 3.2 (I think). My suggestion is to find a different editor

Comment: Perhaps look to the Java-FX [`WebView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html)..

Comment: @MadProgrammer You think right. But then, only a *sub-set* of the HTML 3.2 elements (e.g. no applet or JS support).  While a simple web browser could well do without applet support, 'no JS' is a killer..

Comment: `bookbtn=new JButton(new ImageIcon("Z://Browser/Source/Resources/Images/bkk.jpg"));` By the time of deployment, that resource will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'd have to say this would be one of this reasons I'd consider JavaFX over Swing (I'm an old dog ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer For my part, it would be that and the media player.  It's 'stick with what I know' combined with an healthy cynicism as to what Oracle considers a core API (I'll be convinced only when it makes it into the JSE Java Docs & the Java Tutorial) that holds me back from paying more attention to it..

Comment: @AndrewThompson For my part, JavaFX doesn't know what it wants to be...flash competitor, production user interface, 3D environment...??  I like the idea, but each of those are competing with each other...better to have a core API from which those elements can be plugged in - IMHO

Comment: Use one of ready to use html/css rendering engines. For example CssBox or Flying Saucer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10081084/1240328

Comment: give me some example to parse css.

Comment: how to use that CssBox with java swing