# Why isn't my CSS working right in Java?

Tags: java, html, css, swing

Wondering if you could help me? I'm trying to create some coding in Java to execute html code in a `JEditorPane` by implementing `CSS`.

I get it to implement *some* of the `CSS` coding as a rule, but it seems to ignore the `"float:"` bit in the coding. On JSFiddle ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/xc295/)) I get it to run flawlessly, but on Java/NB it creates the container, left `div` which is small, and the supposed right `div`, but it puts it below the left `div`, instead of to the right of it. What I'm thinking is that Java and `HTMLEditorKit` as well as `StyleSheet` doesn't support what I want to do. Can anybody give some clarity on this?

**Edit:**

It seem that only `HTML 3.2` is supported. Is there a possible workaround for this?

```
import java.awt.Dimension; 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class jBulletins extends JPanel {

    javax.swing.JEditorPane bulletinBoard = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();

    public jBulletins() {

        Dimension d = new Dimension();
        d.setSize(800, 600);

        bulletinBoard.setPreferredSize(d);
        bulletinBoard.setContentType("text/html"); // NOI18N

        add(new JScrollPane(bulletinBoard));

        loadBulletins();
    }

    private void loadBulletins() {

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HTML/CSS Script">
        String eBullStyles = "#divMsgs{ "
                + "height: 99px; "
                + "margin: auto; "
                + "background-color: #3399FF; "
                + "} "
                + "#divLeft{ "
                + "float: left; "
                + "width: 110px; "
                + "height: 85px; "
                + "border: 2px #6666ff outset; "
                + "padding: 5px; "
                + "background-color: #189cd8; "
                + "color: #ffffff; "
                + "font-size: 11px; "
                + "font-weight: normal; "
                + "font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; "
                + "font-style: normal; "
                + "text-decoration: inherit; "
                + "} "
                + "#divRight{ "
                + "float: right; "
                + "width: 50px; "
                + "height: 85px; "
                + "border: 2px #6666ff outset; "
                + "background-color: #189cd8; "
                + "padding: 5px; "
                + "color: #ffffff; "
                + "font-size: 11px; "
                + "font-weight: normal; "
                + "font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; "
                + "font-style: normal; "
                //+ "text-decoration: inherit; "
                + "line-height: 1.3em; "
                + "}"; //</editor-fold>

        bulletinBoard.setContentType("text/html");
        bulletinBoard.setText("");

        HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        bulletinBoard.setEditorKit(kit);

        // add some styles to the html
        StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
        styleSheet.addRule(eBullStyles);

        Document setdoc = kit.createDefaultDocument();
        bulletinBoard.setDocument(setdoc);

        String initial = "<div id=\"divMsgs\">"
                + "<div id=\"divLeft\">"
                + "Hello Bob"
                + "</div>"
                + "<div id=\"divRight\">"
                + "How are you today?"
                + "</div>"
                + "</div>";

        try {
            Document doc = bulletinBoard.getDocument();
            bulletinBoard.setText(initial);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        jBulletins mainPanel = new jBulletins();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bulletin Board");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/package-summary.html), Swing components support only HTML 3.2.

And, according to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html), some CSS properties are not rendered:

> The following describes the CSS properties that are suppored by the rendering engine:
>
> - font-family
> - font-style
> - font-size (supports relative units)
> - font-weight
> - font
> - color
> - background-color (with the exception of transparent)
> - background-image
> - background-repeat
> - background-position
> - background
> - text-decoration (with the exception of blink and overline)
> - vertical-align (only sup and super)
> - text-align (justify is treated as center)
> - margin-top
> - margin-right
> - margin-bottom
> - margin-left
> - margin
> - padding-top
> - padding-right
> - padding-bottom
> - padding-left
> - padding
> - border-top-style
> - border-right-style
> - border-bottom-style
> - border-left-style
> - border-style (only supports inset, outset and none)
> - border-top-color
> - border-right-color
> - border-bottom-color
> - border-left-color
> - border-color
> - list-style-image
> - list-style-type
> - list-style-position
>
> The following are modeled, but currently not rendered.
>
> - font-variant
> - background-attachment (background always treated as scroll)
> - word-spacing
> - letter-spacing
> - text-indent
> - text-transform
> - line-height
> - border-top-width (this is used to indicate if a border should be used)
> - border-right-width
> - border-bottom-width
> - border-left-width
> - border-width
> - border-top
> - border-right
> - border-bottom
> - border-left
> - border
> - width
> - height
> - float
> - clear
> - display
> - white-space
> - list-style

Answer (score 2):

JEditorPane only provides HTML 3.2 support, so I bet it doesn't support all the css properties we are used to.

Comment: There are libraries available that are more advanced than JEditorPane. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438201/pure-java-html-viewer-renderer