# Using JFrame to fetch URL

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm currently working on a Java Program using JFrames. I'm supposed to create a URLFrame in which I can input a web address and ask the program to fetch it and display it in the Frame. So far I am stuck and would like input on if I'm on the right track and where to go from here:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class URLFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel messagelLabel;
    private JTextField enterAddress;
    private JButton fetchButton;
    private JTextArea displayPage;
    private JButton displayScriptCount;
    private JButton writePage;
    private JTextArea checkStatus;

    public URLFrame(){

        setTitle("Enter Address");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code shows nothing about URL fetching, just frame initialization.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143923/why-shouldnt-you-extend-jframe-and-other-components).

Comment: I'm just a little stuck from here. I'm currently working on the text field, but don't know how to get it to display the webpage within the JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for something along these lines

[Pure Java HTML viewer/renderer for use in a Scrollable pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438201/pure-java-html-viewer-renderer)
or 
http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser

Due to the vagueness of the question, that is what I can think up. Both sources have adequate guidance on setups directly or indirectly.

EDIT: To use a textfield as an 'address-bar', use this:

```
String url = jTextField_For_Url_Input.getText();
java.net.URL url_to_connect_to = new java.net.URL(url);
//... whatever needed for implementation
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_url_processing.htm give a good tutorial to help you learn and you can combine this with the suggestions of the HTML related components to view a rendered copy of HTML content.

Another resource using the JEditorPane is [here](http://mrbool.com/display-html-contents-with-java/24532)

Comment: I just want to know how to use JFrame to fetch a URL that I input into a text field. Many of the tutorials I've looked up show something like: URL url=new URL("www.google.com");

Comment: Are you wanting to view the rendered HTML content? Or just source? I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: the rendered html content

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Integrate With the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html).

You can use the examples there to load a URL into the default browser.

The Swing JEditorPane will display basic HTML. Look at the table of contents from the above link and you will find a section on `Text Component Features` that might help.