# Display webpage inside swing application

Tags: java, swing

I would like to display a webpage inside a java swing application. Similar to a when using HTML, but in java Swing. I have able to show webpage inside swing application. But the problem is webpage is not looks good. For example below output when I used the below code :

```
JEditorPane website = new JEditorPane();
website.setEditable(false);
website.setPage("http://www.google.com/");


JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google");
frame.add(new JScrollPane(website));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
```

[image]

Even searching is also not working. I am new in this section. What I missed or what is other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With plain Swing you're out of luck for that. However, if you'd consider switching your technology stack there might be alternatives:

- Java FX [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/overview.htm)
- Eclipse SWT can embed [native Browser widget](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html).
- [CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/)

For others you might want to check out [Pure Java HTML viewer/renderer for use in a Scrollable pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438201/pure-java-html-viewer-renderer)

Comment: How can I use JavaFx WebView? I am using jdk1.7 with Version: Kepler Service Release 2

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#5 - it's bundled with JDK 7 since update 7. So you already have it

Comment: When I used javafx packages then I got this The import javafx cannot be resolved exception.

Comment: Add `jfxrt.jar` to your project dependency. That file is located in your jre7/lib directory.

Answer (score 3):

try using JavaFX. it work perfectly.

```
   JFXPanel fxPanel;
   WebView wv;
   JFrame frame;


  try {

        fxPanel = new JFXPanel ();

        // create JavaFX scene
        com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater ( new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                wv = new WebView ();
                wv.getEngine ().load ( "http://www.google.com/" );
                fxPanel.setScene ( new Scene ( wv, 1000, 750 ) );
                frame = new JFrame ( "Google" );
                frame.add ( new JScrollPane ( fxPanel ) );
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.setVisible ( true );
                frame.pack ();
            }
        } );

    } catch ( Exception ex ) {

    }
```